# Swift: access to the content of a dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, subscript

the codes simple:

```
var dictionnary: [Int: Int] = [25: 32]
var test = "dictionary"

print (dictionary[25])
print (test[25])
```

I want to access to the content the dictionary like in the last line of code.
I have to detect the name of the dictionary i have to use. So I am obliged to store the name of the dictionary in a variable of type String.
a get this error :

[image: error i get with last line of code]

how can I proceed?

Ok, I tried to make a simple example to explain my problem and I made a mistake.
My problem is not related to converting string to a variable name or something else.

In fact I have 10 dictionaries with data in each. I need to identify the good one in order to grab my data.

I obtained a variable of type string containing the name of the good dictionary but when I try to use it to access to the content of this dictionary I obtain the error mentioned.

I will try to explain this correctly when I will be able to post again...

Comment: You cannot proceed - you have to take few steps backwards and rethink what you are doing. You mustn't and cannot access variables by their name.

Comment: thanks for your quick response.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you want

```
var test = dictionary
```

Remove the quotations

Comment: This solve my problem.

Comment: You should note that this is creating a copy, not a reference of `dictionary` due to the nature of value types in Swift (`Dictionary` is a `struct`). Any mutations to your `dictionary` variable will not be reflected on `test`.

Comment: @D.PEPIN if my answer helped you, could you please accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You've already named your dictionary with this code:

```
var dictionary: [Int: Int] = [25: 32]
```

Your dictionary is called "dictionary" (you spelled it incorrectly but I think this is what you were going for.

To access the value for the key 25, you've done that correctly:

```
print (dictionary[25])
```

There's no need to make a variable called test. A string doesn't act like an array in swift, but if it did

```
print(test[25])
```

would be accessing the 26th character in the string "dictionary", which is non-existant.